# Row filtering in SQL Azure Data Sync - is it gone?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I'm going to use SQL Azure Data Sync service to synchronize an SQL Azure and an on-premise database (one-way, from Azure to the on-premise db).

But I need to filter rows to synchronize (based on column value).

E.g., [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/felixmar/archive/2012/06/26/data-synchronization-using-sql-azure-data-sync-part-ii.aspx) tutorial tells how to configure filters, but it refers old Windows Azure portal.

A [newer](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/#Configure) tutorial says:

> If you also want to filter a column so that only rows with specific
>   values (such as, Age>=65) are synchronized, use the SQL Data Sync
>   portal at Azure and the documentation at Select the Tables, Columns,
>   and Rows to Synchronize to define the data to sync.

However, I can't find any link to edit filters in the new Azure portal.

Is this feature gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that feature was not ported in the new UI. Data Sync is a preview product with unclear future, you may want to re-evaluate using it.

Comment: It looks like Data Sync is still around in 2018 and in Preview.
Do you know if this feature for filter will ever be added back in, or what alternate solution that Microsoft can recommend?